# Whenever null is forced into model's field, go to default string

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I have a model like this:

```
class Test(models.Model)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Unassigned")
```

Whenever this model's instance is being saved with `None` in the `name` field, I want the instance to be saved with `"Unassigned"` instead. But if I do this:

```
>>> test = Test()
>>>test.name = None
>>>test.save()
```

It will currently fail with

> django.db.utils.IntegrityError: NOT NULL constraint failed:
>   explorer_api_test.name

on the last line, because obviously the `name` field does not allow nulls (there is no `null=True` in it).

**But** if I allow nulls, it will not save with default `"Unassigned"`, but with `None` instead.

What do I change **in the model definition** so that whenever its instance is trying to be saved with `None` in the field, it is saved with default string instead?
Outside of model definition, I could do this:

```
>>>test = Test()
>>>test.name = None
>>>if test.name is None:
>>>...test.name = "Unassigned"
>>>test.save()
```

but I prefer to have this logic in model itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can override the save method like this:

```
class Test(models.Model):

   field = models.CharField(max_length=30, default="Unassigned", null=True)

   def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
       if self.field == None:
           field_att = self.__class__._meta.get_field('field')
           default_value = field_att.get_default()
           self.field = default_value

       return super(Test, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Thanks! Is `null=True` not redundant  in this case?

Comment: @barciewicz Depends. If you don't plan to expose your model via ModelForm or Serializer then its redundant. But if you do, then it will throw non empty error(this scenario can also be avoided as well, by overriding the `name` field in form/serialzier to accept null value).